# When processing csv file filled with Chinese characters, "pandas.errors.ParserError:C error: EOF inside string starting at row"

Tags: pandas

When I pre-process a csv file which contains Chinese characters and numbers, pandas report "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 676478". The csv file is like shown as this pic [[image]].[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4swZF.png)

Here are lines near the error line.
[image]

My code is

```py
pd.read_csv(in_file, sep="\t", encoding='utf-8')
```

I tried to encode with 'utf-8'. It didn't work.

Comment: I thought it might be caused by the Chinese characters which often causes trouble when encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the line had a string that contained within it a single quote mark.
Here is the solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv
tmp = pd.read_csv(in_file, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')
```